# Using AutoLayout, the background UIView hides content on runtime, but not at design time. Why?

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, autolayout

I've updated my old pre-AutoLayout view to use AutoLayout. All warnings and errors are gone. I can successfully switch the simulated size to any iPhone and it will work.

However, once I run on actual hardware, the UIImageView that I've set as a background image seems to be hiding all the content (either that or the other content is being pushed off). I've verified that the UIImageView is closest to the root, so it should have the lowest z-index position. When I delete the UIImageView, all the content appears as expected.

If this helps: I've pinned the leading, trailing, top and bottom values of the UIImageView to the superview sides and the respective navbar/toolbar edges.

I've since confirmed it's merely covering the other content by setting a transparency value. So for whatever reason, it's getting pulled to the front. If anyone has intimate knowledge of AutoLayout and has some sane reason as to why that's happening, I'd love to hear it, otherwise, I'll chalk it up to just quirkiness.

Comment: It can be useful to run app, pause execution, and at the `(lldb)` prompt, type `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]`. This can be useful in identifying ambiguous layouts (and when constraints are ambiguous, you can get this sort of deviation between design and execution).

Comment: BTW, next time, when you're trying to confirm the frames of views, `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]` can be very useful.

Comment: The z-order of your views doesn't have anything to do with auto layout. Can you post an image of your controller's view hierarchy somewhere?

Comment: Thanks @Rob, that's good to know, I'll mess around with those and report back.

Comment: @rdelmar it's literally one root node (the View) with n children who are all siblings of each other (there are no grandchildren anywhere). The UIImageView in question is child #1 (or at index 0 if you prefer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the underlying XML of the view had issues.

Solution Summary:

- Removed `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO` code.
- Re-dragged background image to original position in hierarchy.

Details:

After digging around with the commands that Rob showed me, I was able to confirm that there were a lot of ambiguous layout errors at runtime only. I couldn't see anything inherently wrong with the constraints in Interface Builder, but after redoing the constraints several times and still having no luck, I removed the following from my view controller code:

`setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO`

That immediately removed the ambiguity errors.

Why did I put that in there? I have no real good reason other than having read some blogs suggesting to do so. Lesson learned, don't blindly do things.

However, this actually still did not fix the original problem. I reran the program and the background image was still jumping to the front of all sibling subviews even though there were no longer any ambiguity errors.

I was able to send it manually to the back by executing

`sendSubviewToBack:` against lldb.

and the view looked as intended. With no ambiguity errors remaining I decided to just drag the background uiimageview to a new position in the view hierarchy, then I executed the code. Then I stopped and dragged the uiimageview back to its original position, and executed again. And voila, it was in the proper position. I can only imagine the underlying XML had problems.